# Is there a difference in `BigQueryIO` when you use `fromTable` vs `fromQuery("SELECT * ...")` in dataflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

When you need to read all the data from one or more tables in bigquery in a dataflow job there are two approaches to it I would say. The first one is to use `BigQueryIO` with `from`, which reads the table in question, and the second approach is to use `fromQuery` where you specify a query that reads all the data from the same table. So my question is:

- Is it any cost or performance benefit for using one over the other?

I haven't find anything in the docs about this, but I would really like to know. I imagine that maybe `read` is faster since you don't need to run a query that scans the data, meaning it is more similar to the preview functionality you have in `BigQuery` UI. If that is true it might also be much cheaper, but it make sense if they both cost the same.

So in short, what is the difference between:

```
BigQueryIO.read(...).from(tableName)
```

And

```
BigQueryIO.read(...).fromQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`from` is both cheaper and faster than `fromQuery(SELECT * FROM ...)`.

- `from` directly exports the table and exporting data is [free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) for BigQuery.
- `fromQuery(SELECT * FROM ...)` will first scan the entire table ($5/TB) and export the result.

Comment: Do you have any docs to point me to, or how do you know this?

Comment: It's in the SDK implementation. `from` corresponds to [`BigQueryTableSource`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryTableSource.java) where it kicks off an export directly. `fromQuery` corresponds to [`BigQueryQuerySource`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryQuerySource.java) where it creates temp dataset, executes query, exports and cleans up temp resources.

Comment: @JiayuanMa is spot on. `read()` invokes an export of the table to GCS under-the-hood (free), whereas `readFromQuery()` issues an actual SQL query to BigQuery and you pay for it.